# Dockerfile with nextjs and puppteer permission denied

Tags: docker, next.js, puppeteer

I've been struggling for months on this. I don't understand why I run into this permission issues. I'm on Centos7 and it works on my local machine, but when I try and deploy to server I get this error.

```
FROM node:12-slim

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# If running Docker >= 1.13.0 use docker run's --init arg to reap zombie processes, otherwise
# uncomment the following lines to have `dumb-init` as PID 1
# ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

# Uncomment to skip the chromium download when installing puppeteer. If you do,
# you'll need to launch puppeteer with:
#     browser.launch({executablePath: 'google-chrome-stable'})
# ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install puppeteer so it's available in the container.
RUN npm i puppeteer \
    # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
    # same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space
#    && groupadd -r node && useradd -r -g node -G audio,video node \
        && mkdir -p /home/node/Downloads \
        && mkdir -p /home/node/.next/static \
        && mkdir -p /home/node/node_modules \
   && mkdir -p /home/node/node_modules  \
    && chown -R node:node /home/node \
    && chown -R node:node /node_modules \
        && chown -R node:node /home/node \
        && chown -R node:node /home/node/.next/static \
        && chmod -R 777 /home/node/.next


# Run everything after as non-privileged user.


#RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app
RUN chown -Rh $user:$user /home/node
RUN $user
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
#RUN yarn install -g --unsafe-perm next
RUN ls -la /home/node/.next/static

WORKDIR /home/node

COPY . .
USER node

RUN yarn install  && yarn run build

EXPOSE 7000

CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

on docker-compose build; docker-compose up we the following issue. I've tried npm and arn.

```
$ next build
info  - Creating an optimized production build...

> Build error occurred
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/node/.next/cache/config.json.1544779693'
    
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

What do I need to do to get this to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created **next.config.js** *distDir* directive to

> ---
>
> build

---

at the root of the next.js project and the permissions issues were solved in Docker.

```
module.exports = {
      distDir: 'build',
      serverRuntimeConfig: {
        // Will only be available on the server side
        apiUrl: 'http://signup-api:1984'
      },
      publicRuntimeConfig: {
        // Will be available on both server and client
        apiUrl: 'http://localhost:1984'
      }
    }
```